# can you print a record in awk

Tags: shell, awk

Probably a simple question but I haven't found an answer. I have a file with multiple records separated by a blank line. Each field in the file is separated by a newline. I simply want to print out the entire first record or the entire third record.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="";} {print $1}' output.txt
```

The above prints out the first letter of each line of the first record

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""} {print $1}' output.txt
```

The above prints out the first field of the first record.

It seems a simple enough problem but I can't seem to solve it. Records have an indeterminate amount of fields (lines). They are simply separated by a blank line

A

ok here is a sample:

```
line1 record1
line2 record1
line3 record1
line4 record1

line1 record2
line2 record2
line3 record2
line4 record2
line5 record2

line1 record3

line1 record4
line2 record4
```

Now I want the entire first record and the entire 3rd record.

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR==3 {print $0}' output.txt
line1 record1
line3 record1
```

First and third lines of first record. no good

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR==3' output.txt
line1 record1
line3 record1
```

First and third lines of first record. no good

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR==3 {print $0}' output.txt
line1 record1
line3 record1
```

First and 3rd line of the first record. no good.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""} NR==1' output.txt
line1 record1
line2 record1
line3 record1
line4 record1

line1 record2
line2 record2
line3 record2
line4 record2
line5 record2

line1 record3

line1 record4
line2 record4
```

All printed out. no good

I simply want the first and third records.
The first being:

```
line1 record1
line2 record1
line3 record1
line4 record1
```

and the third being:

```
line1 record3
```

Ok so nothing spelled out seems to work for me and I'm well confused. Here is the shell output:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR ~ /^(1|3)$/' output.txt
line1 record1
line2 record1
line3 record1
line4 record1

line1 record2
line2 record2
line3 record2
line4 record2
line5 record2

line1 record3

line1 record4
line2 record4

$ cat output.txt
line1 record1
line2 record1
line3 record1
line4 record1

line1 record2
line2 record2
line3 record2
line4 record2
line5 record2

line1 record3

line1 record4
line2 record4
$
```

I am very confused as to why this isn't working.

here is my system and the awk I'm using:

```
$ awk -V | head -1
GNU Awk 4.0.1
$ uname -a
Linux IEDUB2TJ5262 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06   UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
```

Is there something I could be missing here?

A

Comment: so you want to print the 1st and 3rd lines? It would be useful to show some sample input and desired output to make it more clear.

Comment: I want to print out a record, not lines (fields)

Comment: Are your blank lines truly empty? Do they contain any whitespace (spaces, tabs, carriage returns)?

Comment: use the example from above. The blank lines are simply blank lines. enter in vi

Comment: For kicks, could you check what `cat -vet output.txt` shows? That will help us understand if there's something strange about your input file that would cause awk to misinterpret things.

Answer (score 2):

This is **THE** idiomatic awk way to do what you want and it works in all awks, not just gawk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR ~ /^(1|3)$/' file
line1 record1
line2 record1
line3 record1
line4 record1

line1 record3
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line and google `awk paragraph mode`.

If the above does not work for you then there is something wrong with your input file (or, far less likely, your awk is broken).

Comment: Ed, I don't see the word "paragraph" in the man pages for either gawk or FreeBSD's awk. What man page are you reading?

Comment: I confess, it's been a long time since I actually read an awk man page so I may be mis-remembering what they contain. If it's not mentioned there then just google `awk paragparaph mode`. I updated the text under my answer, thanks.

Comment: I forgive you. :-)  Thanks for constantly sharing your awesome expertise.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [an answer you gave in March](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29359256/1072112) (and probably other times as well)

Comment: Yeah, I expect this one's been answered many times. There's been severeal other answers that should have "worked" for the OP though so I think he has some other issue that hasn't been uncovered yet so we may as well start with the right answer to the question he asked and then debug it from there when this doesn't work for him either.

Comment: I appreciate all your help here. I posted an edit. Nothing seems to work for me and I'm sure that some of the answers posted should work. Dunno what I'm missing but I put my awk version and system details in the edit

Comment: There IS something wrong with your input file so debug it in the usual way - add some printfs to your script t, e.g. throw a `printf "%d,%d,<%s:%s>\n", NR, NF, $0, RT` in there and see if it matches your expectations or throws any light on how awk is carving up your file.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR==3 {print $0}' output.txt
```

Everything before the curly braces is called a restriction.
It will determine whether the command (everything within the parentheses) will be executed. `NR` means *Number of Record*, so it means that output will be restricted to the first and third record.

Every `awk` program is just a collection of *restrictions* and *commands*.

EDIT:
Actually I just realized that `{print $0}` is the default action, if no command is provided, this means that:

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR==3' output.txt
```

is sufficient.

EDIT:

After you've explained yourself a bit more, I suggest this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS='\n\n'} NR==1 || NR==3' output.txt
```

It considers everything a record, that is seperated from each other by two newlines.

Comment: that prints out the first 2 fields of the first record

Comment: Ok, you made it really confusing. *Record* is a term used in the Awk language and refers to Lines, *Fields* is a term used in the Awk language and refers to elements in a record seperated by RS (usually whitespace).  Refer to my edit above

Comment: I know but in my case the fields (or elements of a record) are lines and the records (grouping of fields) are separated by a blank line

Comment: the edited version (awk 'BEGIN {RS='\n\n'} NR==1 || NR==3' output.txt) still does not work. all records are printed out

Comment: @henrikgiesel, an awk record is not always a line. If you redefine the `RS` variable, you control if a record contains multiple lines or even only part of a line.

Comment: create a simple file and post that simple from above. Its not as easy to do this as I thought it would be. Maybe I'm missing something though

Comment: @amadain I have tested it on a file just now, and it worked. Are you sure, there are two newlines between each _Record_?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes I know, but it is the default, which is why I was confused by the initial question

Comment: I just went into vi with the exact file as stated above and deleted each blank line and pressed enter at the end of each record to recreate the blank lines and the above awk still didn't work on it

Comment: @amadain Does the file have Windows-style `\r\n` line endings? Try `head -2 file | od -c`

Comment: and I manually created the file from a shell in ubuntu

Comment: That doesn't mean anything about the contents of the file. In vi, do `:set ff`

Comment: ok so I :set ff and ran awk 'BEGIN {RS='\n\n'} NR==1 || NR==3' output.txt and it printed the entire file. Does it work for you with the exact same file?

Comment: [Try it here](http://goo.gl/420efg). Just enter `awk -f main.awk < testfile`

Comment: thanks I just tried it in tutorialspoint and got an error. When I changed the quotes I still only got fields in the records jumbled. This should not be so hard

Comment: Only GNU awk supports an RS that's more than one character so chances are the OP is not using gawk which is why `RS="\n\n"` is not working for him.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""} NR==1' output.txt
```

prints the first record.

Comment: that prints out all records

Comment: If the fields and records are separated as described in the question this should work fine. if you can give sample input and output would be nice.

Comment: I just posted an example

Comment: For the sample you have provided `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""} NR==1||NR==3'` gets the desired output for me. I use GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: GNU Awk 4.0.1 but the lower version couldn't be the issue could it?

Comment: I retried awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""} NR==1||NR==3' output.txt on it and I still get the entire file printing out

Comment: No. I suppose. It has to do do something with text formatting as pointed out by glenn jackman

Comment: if it prints the entire line for the above command `FS="\n"` doesn't separate the fields.

Comment: I tried \r\n instead of \n but still get the entire file printing out