# How to use grep / awk to do aggregation average across multiple lines?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep, find

Assume that I have a bunch of files with the following patterns:

File 1:

```
 head1
 random words
 number=100
 random words
 ...
 head2
 random words
 number=200
 random words
 ...
 head1
 random words
 number=200
 random words
 ...
```

File 2:

```
 head1
 random words
 number=1000
 random words
 ...
 head2
 random words
 number=200
 random words
 ...
 head1
 random words
 number=2000
 random words
 ...
```

I would like to see which file is having bigger number on average under `head1`, in this case, File 1 is having `(100 + 200) / 2 = 150` while File 2 is having `(1000 + 2000)/2 = 1500`.

So I would like to just print out this result in any format, but one might be like:

```
File 1: 150
File 2: 1500
```

I am quite new with linux commands, can anyone help me to figure this out?

Comment: grep is for finding text, not for processing them further like arithmetic operations... use awk(https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) for that

Comment: Yours is a combined duplicate of "how do I extract something from a multi-line record" and "how do I calculate an average from values I have extracted". Both are easy to do in Awk and you should end up with basically a one-liner or a two-liner. Search for solutions to these two problems; there are plenty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357919/how-to-parse-multi-line-records-with-awk

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149731/use-awk-to-find-average-of-a-column

Comment: Doesn't seem like the headers are relevant.  You can get most of the way with `awk '$1 == "number" {sum+=$2} END {print sum}' FS== input-file`

Answer (score -1):

## script

```
  #!/bin/csh
  foreach x (file1 file2 file3)
        echo -n $x" :"
        sed -n '/head1/,/\.\.\./p' $x |\
        awk -F "=" ' BEGIN{sum=0;cnt=0}\
                 /number/{sum=sum+$2;cnt++}\
                 END{if(cnt)print sum/cnt;else print " " sum}'  
   end
```

## output for 3 files

```
 file1 : 150
 file2 : 2000
 file3 : 0
```

## explanation

1) run on all relevant files with `foreach x (file1 file2 file3)`

2) print file name whithout end of line `echo -n $x" :"`

3) contains only relevant parts of original file
`sed -n '/head1/,/\.\.\./p' $x |\`
 (`sed -n` silent , `/first str/,/second str/p` in between the 2 strings, `$x` file's name from loop)

4)   set field separator to be "="  `awk -F "="`,set sum and count to calculate average  `BEGIN{sum=0;cnt=0}`, if line contains number inc cnt and sum value after "=" car `/number/{sum=sum+$2;cnt++}`

5) check if there where any numbers to sum, if there were print average else print 0 `END{if(cnt)print " "sum/cnt;else print " " sum}'`

## input files

**file1: 100+200=300 300/2=150**

```
  head1
  random words
  number=100
  random words
  ...
  head2
  random words
  number=200
  random words
  ...
  head1
  random words
  number=200
  random words
  ...
```

**file2: 1000+2000+3000=6000 6000/3=2000**

```
  head1
  random words
  number=1000
  random words
  ...
  head1
  random words
  number=2000
  random words
  ...
  head1
  random words
  number=3000
  random words
  ...
```

**file3: no head1 -> 0**

```
  head3
  random words
  number=200
  random words
  ...
  head4
  random words
  number=200
  random words
  ...
  head5
  random words
  number=500
  random words
  ...
```

Comment: The parts inside the loop are vaguely useful, though the `sed` script obviously is easy to avoid; but the temp file and the use of `csh` are *extremely* dubious.