# how to club the names with space in between in AWK

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

i am trying to use a awk command to filter out data from the file and get it into a CSV file. I am trying to create the column headers but the data has space between them so the script is taking each character as separate name.

Script i am using

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat file |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = ","
        numTags = split("Machine Name Type Node Name Agent Name Operating System Agent Release Agent Build",tags)
        for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            printf "\"%s\"%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }

    !NF || /^\/\*/ { next }
    { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }

    match($0,/[[:space:]]job_type:/) {
        if ( jobNr++ ) {
            prt()
            delete tag2val
        }

        # save "insert_job" value
        tag = substr($1,1,length($1)-1)
        val = substr($0,length($1)+1,RSTART-(length($1)+2))
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",val)
        tag2val[tag] = val

        # update $0 to start with "job_type" to look like all other input
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+1)
    }

    {
        tag = val = $0
        sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }

    END { prt() }

    function prt(    tagNr,tag,val) {
        for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            val = tag2val[tag]
            printf "\"%s\"%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
'
```

Contents of `File`:

```
$ cat file

Machine Name:       machine1
Type:               a
Node Name:          machine1.test
Agent Name:         WA_AGENT
Operating System:   Windows Server 2012 
Agent Release:      12.0
Agent Build:        6181, Service Pack 00, Maintenance Level 00

Machine Name:       machine2
Type:               a
Node Name:          machine2.test
Agent Name:         WA_AGENT
Operating System:   Windows Server 2012 for amd64
Agent Release:      12.0
Agent Build:        6181, Service Pack 00, Maintenance Level 00
```

Output i am getting:

```
"Machine","Name","Type","Node","Name","Agent","Name","Operating","System","Agent","Release","Agent","Build"
"","","a","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Required output:

```
"Machine Name","Type","Node Name","Agent Name","Operating System","Agent Release","Agent Build"
"machine1"," a","  machine1.test","  AGENT","  Windows Server 2012","  12.0","  6181, Service Pack 00, Maintenance Level 00"
"machine2"," a","  machine2.test","  AGENT","  Windows Server 2012","  12.0","  6181, Service Pack 00, Maintenance Level 00"
```

Is there a way to get the output that i want.

Comment: Your input is ambiguous. How should either Awk or we know which spaces are field separators as opposed to word separators within a field name? Use a different delimiter and split on that instead, like `split("value one:value two:third value", array, ":")`

Comment: Your question seem analog to [this one about multi line records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357919/how-to-parse-multi-line-records-with-awk)

Comment: 1) Your previous question had an initial line in each block that was different from  the rest (it contained 2 tag-value pairs instead of 1) while this one doesn't. 2)  in your previous question you wanted to output a subset of the tag-value pairs from the input while in this one you just want to print all of them. 3) In your previous question you had multiple blank lines and commented lines to be ignored between blocks of data while in this one you don't. Given that, my solution to THIS question would not use the solution to your previous question as a starting point, it'd be a bit different.

Comment: So do you really want to know how to enhance the script in your question to handle this input/output, or do you want the solution we'd come up with from scratch to handle this input/output?

Comment: do you really want the data fields to include a leading space (eg, `" a"`)?

Comment: The ruby solution I posted on your other questions works for your example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the leading blanks in some output fields as idk if/why you'd want those and you can tweak this to add them if you really do, here's how to modify the code in your question to do what you want:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat file |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = ","
        numTags = split("Machine Name:Type:Node Name:Agent Name:Operating System:Agent Release:Agent Build",tags,":")
        for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            printf "\"%s\"%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }

    !NF || /^\/\*/ { next }
    { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }

    /^Machine Name:/ {
        if ( jobNr++ ) {
            prt()
            delete tag2val
        }
    }

    {
        tag = val = $0
        sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }

    END { prt() }

    function prt(    tagNr,tag,val) {
        for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            val = tag2val[tag]
            printf "\"%s\"%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
"Machine Name","Type","Node Name","Agent Name","Operating System","Agent Release","Agent Build"
"machine1","a","machine1.test","WA_AGENT","Windows Server 2012","12.0","6181, Service Pack 00, Maintenance Level 00"
"machine2","a","machine2.test","WA_AGENT","Windows Server 2012 for amd64","12.0","6181, Service Pack 00, Maintenance Level 00"
```

In reality, if I were to do this from scratch for this specific problem, I wouldn't hard-code tags in the question, I'd just print all values every time a blank line was hit. For example:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat file |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = ","
    }

    { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }

    !NF {
        prt()
        delete tag2val
        numTags = 0
        next
    }

    {
        tag = val = $0
        sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
        if ( !(tag in tag2val) ) {
            tags[++numTags] = tag
        }
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }

    END { prt() }

    function prt(    tagNr,tag,val) {
        if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
            for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
                tag = tags[tagNr]
                printf "\"%s\"%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }

        for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            val = tag2val[tag]
            printf "\"%s\"%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
"Machine Name","Type","Node Name","Agent Name","Operating System","Agent Release","Agent Build"
"machine1","a","machine1.test","WA_AGENT","Windows Server 2012","12.0","6181, Service Pack 00, Maintenance Level 00"
"machine2","a","machine2.test","WA_AGENT","Windows Server 2012 for amd64","12.0","6181, Service Pack 00, Maintenance Level 00"
```

One thing to note about any of the scripts I've provided for you - I do not use fields such as $1 and $2 to hold the tag or value because as soon as you do that you run into problems if your data can contain whatever you use as an FS.

For example, if you have data that looks like:

```
tag: value
```

then do not do anything like this in your code:

```
FS = ": *"
tag = $1
val = $2
```

as it'll fail when the value (or, far less likely, the tag) contains a string that matches the `FS`, such as `:` in this case, e.g. given this data:

```
foo: "the ratio was 2:1"
```

you'd end up with `val` set to `"the ratio was 2`. Instead do this:

```
tag = val = $0
sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
sub(/^:+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
```

so you end up with `val` set to `"the ratio was 2:1"`.

Comment: I would also like to see your other solution for this problem.

Comment: I just added it.